Google Sheet Query - Language
Good day! I hope someone can assist me. I'm having an issue with my B6 cell (Morning Shift time),
I think (if I'm correct) this line has a problem but i just can't figure out what's wrong with it.
IF(B6\<\>"", "AND Col6 \>= datetime '"&TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&" " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "' AND Col7 \<= datetime '"&IF(TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss")\<"12:00:00", TEXT(INT(A6+1), "yyyy-mm-dd"), TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")) & " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "' AND Col6 \>= datetime '"&TEXT(A6+F2, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' AND Col7 \<= datetime '"&TEXT(A6+F3, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'", "")

The time checker in Nightshift (8am to 7:59am) is working fine but if i try to check the morning shift (8am to 7:59Pm) its not working, for example, if i put 1 or 2 or 3 etc "PM" and leave the C6 empty the result is "No result" i can't figure out why, it should be check between 8am to 1 or 2, or 3pm depends on what i place in B6.
Here's the example sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HoTcJevckGHItuTpwoH4QVUXa-4w6Azr3_wlJQPxRW0/edit?gid=493358240#gid=493358240

I've noticed that there are redundancies in the condition of  IF(B6<>"", "AND Col6 >= datetime '"&TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&" " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") &  "' AND Col7 <= datetime '"&IF(TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss")<"12:00:00", TEXT(INT(A6+1), "yyyy-mm-dd"), TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")) &  " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "'", ""). Can you try changing that to IF(B6<>"", "AND Col6 >= datetime '"&TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&" " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "' AND Col7 <= datetime '"&TEXT(A6+1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "'", "").

AND Col7 <= datetime '"&IF(TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss")<"12:00:00", TEXT(INT(A6+1), "yyyy-mm-dd"), TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")) &  " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "'", "") is not returning  TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss")<"12:00:00" because 8/18/2024 1:00:00 is less than 12 hours. Upon checking TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")) & " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss"), which is equivalent to 8/18/2024 1:00:00 PM, the condition checks it as AND Col6 >= datetime '2024-08-18 13:00:00' AND Col7 <= datetime '2024-08-18 13:00:00' which is the same date and time.

This gives the No result you're getting and adding +1 to the date of TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")) & " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") should resolve this since it'll now check AND Col6 >= datetime '2024-08-18 13:00:00' AND Col7 <= datetime '2024-08-19 13:00:00'.

Hello, Sir Lime Husky, I changed the formula based on your suggestions and it's working, thank you for the explanation. However, I'm still facing an issue with the morning shift. I want to handle morning and night shift times correctly. The morning shift is from 8 AM to 7:59 PM, and the night shift is from 8 PM to 7:59 AM the next morning. For example, if B6 is set to 1 PM, the result should show the time range from 8 AM to 1 PM, and vice versa for the night shift (The complete result should always based in B6 others are just optional if just incase they forgot the time) Thanks again Sir.

Can I assume that the Time Incident should be covered / in-between the check-in time and check out time? If so, you may try this: IF(B6<>"", "AND Col6 <= datetime '"&TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&" " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "' AND Col7 <= datetime '"&TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "'", "") &

Hello, Sir Lime Husky, I changed again the formula based on your suggestion in my real sheet and it's working correctly now. Thank you so much! Wishing you good health and safety always. (Bowing)

Let me post this as an answer since it works for you, so you can accept it.

Adjust Your Conditional Statement for Incident Report
Modify your formula from:
IF(B6<>"", "AND Col6 >= datetime '"&TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&" " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") &  "' AND Col7 <= datetime '"&IF(TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss")<"12:00:00", TEXT(INT(A6+1), "yyyy-mm-dd"), TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")) &  " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "'", "")

to:
IF(B6<>"", "AND Col6 <= datetime '"&TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd")&" " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "' AND Col7 >= datetime '"&TEXT(A6, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & TEXT(B6, "hh:mm:ss") & "'", "")

This modified conditional statement will check if the Incident Time is between the Check-in and Check-out time.
